# Javascript: how to use the operator ** in a conditional

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, exponential, ternary

I want to found a operator in a string, like this `"3+7"`, identify the operator and do the sum. I have a peace of code that do that for the operators `+` `-` `*` `/` but not for `**`, my code return my a boolean.

I want to know why this happen and how to use the exponential operator has a conditional.

```
// To know if the string have a "+", "-", "*", "**" or "/" inside of him
let foundCharacterFunction = function(str, char) {
 for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if (str[i] == char) {
     return char;
   } 
 }
 return false;
};


// With this we can use the specific character founded
let characterFoundAlready = foundCharacterFunction("3+7", "+");


// "characterFoundAlready" always is a string but work with all, less with exponential operator
console.log(typeof characterFoundAlready);


// To know what we going to do if we have one character or other
let enterTheCondition = 
 (characterFoundAlready === "+" ) ? console.log("We going to sum!") :
 (characterFoundAlready === "-" ) ? console.log("We going to rest!") :
 (characterFoundAlready === "*" ) ? console.log("We going to multiply!") :
 (characterFoundAlready === "**" ) ? console.log("We going to power!!") :
 (characterFoundAlready === "/" ) ? console.log("We going to divide!") :
 console.log("That character it can't be procesed");
```

Thanks in advance, for your time and attention.

Comment: You're expecting a single character to `===` a two-character string. That's impossible.

Comment: `if (str[i] == char)` checks for a SINGLE character at a time.  If you want to check for a TWO CHARACTER token (like `**`), then you need to somehow [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)  your input string.  SUGGESTION: consider using  [string.includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: Use string not char, I’ve added simple example in answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read about [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)
Algo operates commands, not chars and allow to process different priority operation. And you should too.

EDIT:

Here is some small example how to deal with it:

```
const opertaionDescriptions = [
  { operation: '+', message: 'We going to sum!' },
  { operation: '-', message: 'We going to rest!' },
  { operation: '*', message: 'We going to multiply!' },
  { operation: '**', message: 'We going to power!' },
  { operation: '/', message: 'We going to divide!' },
];

let foundCharacterFunction = function (str) {
  const found = str.match(/[\d\s]([+*/-]+)[\s\d]/i);
  if (found && found[1]) {
    return found[1];
  }

  return false;
};

// With this we can use the specific character founded
let characterFoundAlready = foundCharacterFunction("3+7");

// To know what we going to do if we have one character or other
console.log(
  (opertaionDescriptions.find(({operation}) => operation === characterFoundAlready) 
    || { message: "That character it can't be procesed"})
  .message
); 

// With this we can use the specific character founded
characterFoundAlready = foundCharacterFunction("3 ** 7");

// To know what we going to do if we have one character or other
console.log(
  (opertaionDescriptions.find(({operation}) => operation === characterFoundAlready) 
    || { message: "That character it can't be procesed"})
  .message
);
```

Of course you can still define exact operation to search by creating Regexp manually, smth like `/[\d\s](char_or_string_to_search)[\s\d]/i`

Comment: The problem isn't "infix" vs. "RPN".  The problem is that the OP's naive approach to "parsing" happens to work for an infix expression where the operand is a single character - and fails if the operand happens to be multiple characters.  The solution is to change the way he identifies the operand (i.e. to "parse differently")